# $(a^2+b^2)\mid (ax+by)$, implies $\gcd(x^2+y^2,a^2+b^2)>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a,b,x,y$ are natural number such that $(a^2+b^2)\mid (ax+by)$, prove that $\gcd(x^2+y^2,a^2+b^2)>1$. Can anyone give me a hint to solve the problem? I am rather stuck, thanks!

Comment: This isn't true if $a=1$ and $b=0$; you probably need that your numbers are $>0$.

Comment: Presumably here "natural number" means "positive integer".

Answer (score 1):

First notice that $$(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=(ax+by)^2+(bx-ay)^2$$
If $a=da_1$ and $b=db_1$ where $(a_1, b_1) = 1$ the equation can be rewritten as $$(a_1^2+b_1^2)(x^2+y^2)=(a_1x+b_1y)^2+(b_1x-a_1y)^2$$

Suppose now that $p$ is a prime such that $p \mid a_1^2+b_1^2$. Since we have $$d^2(a_1^2+b_1^2)=(a^2+b^2)\mid (ax+by)=d(a_1x+b_1y)\rightarrow d(a_1^2+b_1^2) \mid (a_1x+b_1y)$$ we would get that $p \mid a_1x + b_1y$ and hence from the equation it follows that $p \mid (b_1x-a_1y)$. So we would have that $$p \mid y(a_1x+b_1y) + x(b_1x-a_1y)=b_1(x^2+y^2)$$ Notice that $p \not \mid b_1$ since otherwise we would have that $p \mid b_1$ and from $p \mid a_1^2+b_1^2$ we would get that $p \mid a_1$ and that would effectively mean that $(a_1, b_1) \not = 1$. So we are left with the option of $p \mid x^2+y^2$. Since $p \mid d^2(a_1^2+b_1^2)= a^2+b^2$ we get that $(a^2+b^2, x^2+y^2)$ is at least $p$.

Comment: Looks nice, but how to pick  $p$ here when $a=b=2$?

Comment: @drhab yes, you are right there is a mistake. I'll try to find a fix otherwise I'll just delete the post. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you can fix it. Succes.

Comment: I will have a look at it after some time, just to give you the opportunity to get finished with your edits. If I cannot find mistakes in it then I will upvote.

Comment: Cannot find mistakes (+1). Maybe the proof can be written on a more elegant way: first prove it under the extra condition that $\left(a,b\right)=1$ and after that the general case as a consequence of this limited version. But I am not sure and leave that up to you.